# php filters pictures as Instagrama

Tags: php

I found on: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-instagram-filters-with-php--net-24504

Cool script for applying filters to images (instagran=m's):

```
error_reporting(ALL);
//phpinfo();

class Instagraph 
{

    public $_image = NULL;
    public $_output = NULL;
    public $_prefix = 'IMG';
    private $_width = NULL;
    private $_height = NULL;
    private $_tmp = NULL;

    public static function factory($image, $output)
    {
        return new Instagraph($image, $output);
    }

    public function __construct($image, $output)
    {
        if(file_exists($image))
        {
            $this->_image = $image;
            list($this->_width, $this->_height) = getimagesize($image);
            $this->_output = $output;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('File not found. Aborting.');
        }
    }

    public function tempfile()
    {
        # copy original file and assign temporary name
        $this->_tmp = $this->_prefix.rand();
        copy($this->_image, $this->_tmp);
    }

    public function output()
    {
        # rename working temporary file to output filename
        rename($this->_tmp, $this->_output);
    }

    public function execute($command)
    {
        # remove newlines and convert single quotes to double to prevent errors
        $command = str_replace(array("\n", "'"), array('', '"'), $command);
        $command = escapeshellcmd($command);
        # execute convert program
        exec($command);
    }

    /** ACTIONS */

    public function colortone($input, $color, $level, $type = 0)
    {
        $args[0] = $level;
        $args[1] = 100 - $level;
        $negate = $type == 0? '-negate': '';

        $this->execute("convert 
        {$input} 
        ( -clone 0 -fill '$color' -colorize 100% ) 
        ( -clone 0 -colorspace gray $negate ) 
        -compose blend -define compose:args=$args[0],$args[1] -composite 
        {$input}");
    }

    public function border($input, $color = 'black', $width = 20)
    {
        $this->execute("convert $input -bordercolor $color -border {$width}x{$width} $input");
    }

    public function frame($input, $frame)
    {
        $this->execute("convert $input ( '$frame' -resize {$this->_width}x{$this->_height}! -unsharp 1.5×1.0+1.5+0.02 ) -flatten $input");
    }

    public function vignette($input, $color_1 = 'none', $color_2 = 'black', $crop_factor = 1.5)
    {
        $crop_x = floor($this->_width * $crop_factor);
        $crop_y = floor($this->_height * $crop_factor);

        $this->execute("convert 
        ( {$input} ) 
        ( -size {$crop_x}x{$crop_y} 
        radial-gradient:$color_1-$color_2
        -gravity center -crop {$this->_width}x{$this->_height}+0+0 +repage )
        -compose multiply -flatten 
        {$input}");   
    }
}
try
{
$instagraph = Instagraph::factory('input.jpg', 'output.jpg');
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}

// loop through all filters

foreach(array('gotham', 'toaster', 'nashville', 'lomo', 'kelvin') as $method)
{
    $instagraph->_output = $method.'.jpg'; // we have to change output file to prevent overwrite
    $instagraph->$method(); // apply current filter (from array)
}
```

On the server I have installed both the GD and ImageMagick.

After running the script on the screen, nothing happens (I have a white screen) - without errors, etc.
Photos also not generate wink.gif know someone can why this is happening?

Comment: *nothing happens (I have a white screen) - without errors* sure? did you check log files, is php configured to display errors?

Comment: yes., I'm check

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions and it worked: "It's easy to use these effects! I'll assume that you saved all the code within instagraph.php file. Now, create a file, called filter.php and copy the code below that suits you."

The code also hardcodes the input image as input.jpg which you will need in the same folder.

Comment: yes, I have input.img

maybe I have bad php config: ow.ly/pBM0306LY8v - can you check?

Comment: Have you checked Imagemagick is installed with some simple code like convert input.jpg output.png If you have version 7 installed it should be magick rather than convert. Imagemagick is an external program and will not show up in php info